# Does the Cloak of the Obsidian Order have any use?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm a Kickstarter Backer, so when I start a new character, in addition to my wonderful space pig and ring, I start with a cape! Specifically, the **Cloak of the Obsidian Order**. Which has some lovely flavor text saying nice things about the sort of people that backed the game, but, when equipped, doesn't seem to *do* anything. There's not even a cosmetic appearance!

Is there any reason to keep this around, or can I just sell it for some extra starting cash?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a use but it does put a cloak on whomever you equip it on.

Comment: It's not doing so on my Orlan... :(

Comment: Oh hey, the reason it's not doing so on my Orlan is because Cloaks are bugged on OS X! YAY!